# Resizing an image before checkin on Oracle UCM

Tags: oracle-ucm

We are running Oracle UCM 10gr3.

We have a form where users can upload their profile image

```
<form id="profile_image">
    <input type="hidden" name="IdcService" value="CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL">
    <input type="file" name="primaryFile" id="pic" accept="image/*">
    <input type="hidden" name="dDocName" value="PROFILE_IMAGE_username">
    <input type="hidden" name="dDocTitle" value="Profile Image: user full name">
    <input type="hidden" name="dDocType" value="Image">
    <input type="hidden" name="dSecurityGroup" value="Content">
    <input type="hidden" name="xWebsites" value="WEBSITE">
    <input type="hidden" name="RedirectUrl" value="/people/?user=username">
    <input id="upload" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">    
</form>
```

We have a requirement for the image which the user submits, to be automatically re-sized (bounding box) before it's checked in to the content server.

Is there a way of creating UCM service in Java which accepts all those parameters in the form, re-sizes the image and submits it to CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL? Or is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do this out of the box with Digital Asset Manager (DAM).

You could also write a custom component that has a custom service which can accept any parameters, resize the image (using a library of your choice or DAM) and checkin the image to WebCenter content.

https://blogs.oracle.com/OracleWebCenterSuite/entry/how_to_create_custom_components

Answer (score 0):

I think a custom (or pre-made?) conversion in the IBR server could do the trick as well, even outputting the profile picture in a preset image format (jpg for example) no matter what kind was uploaded.